# Spring don´t find Interface packaging into a external jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a problem with Spring MVC.

I have a Spring bean that implements an interface packing inside a jar.

Look the schema below:

MyJarInterfaces.jar
  |
  +-- IService.class

In my MVN project this Package (MyJarInterfaces.jar) was described as a dependency.

In my project structure, I have my bean implements IService.class.

```
package com.beans.spring

public class Service implements IService {
...
}
```

In my Spring MVC XML configuration () I have :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.beans.spring" />
```

So .... when I run my project using maven and tomcat plugin (`mvn clean install tomcat:run`) my Tomcat throw an exception :

> Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
>   class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class [com.beans.spring.Service]; nested
>   exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [IService .class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

...

But when I copy my war file after run `mvn clean install` into my TomCat server it works fine.

I have this problem when I run using maven plugin.

Comment: Have you tried to execute first mvn clean install and afterwards mvn tomcat:run?

Comment: Hi @mrkernelpanic, yes I tried this too. So ... always fail when I try to run with maven tomcat plugin.